# JavaScript Objects: Why are value1.a[x] and value2.b[x] returned as undefined since a[x] = a and b[x] = b which are properties of value1 and value2?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
value1 = {a:5, b:6}, value2 = {a:8, b:7};
let a = Object.keys(value1), b = Object.keys(value2);
  for (let x = 0; x < a.length; x ++) { 
    if (a[x] === b[x] && value1.a[x] === value2.b[x]) {
      console.log(a[x], b[x], value1.a[x], value2.b[x]);
    }
  }
// -> a, a, undefined, undefined
```

P.S. I know the other ways to compare objects; just wanted to find out why this doesn't work.

Comment: `value1.a` is a number and `x` is a number, so `value1.a[x]` is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation you are using:

```js
value1.a[x]
```

is trying to refer to the `a` property of `value1` as an array (or other indexable object e.g. a string), indexed by `x`. Since `value1.a` is a number, this returns undefined.

To refer to the property of `value1` whose name is `a[x]`, you should instead use

```js
value1[a[x]]
```

For example:

```js
value1 = {
  a: 5,
  b: 6
}, value2 = {
  a: 5,
  b: 7
};
let a = Object.keys(value1),
  b = Object.keys(value2);
for (let x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
  if (a[x] === b[x] && value1[a[x]] === value2[b[x]]) {
    console.log(a[x], b[x], value1[a[x]], value2[b[x]]);
  }
}
```

Note that if `value1.a` and `value2.b` are strings, your code as is will work (although it will give unexpected results). For example:

```js
value1 = {
  a: 'abc',
  b: 6
}, value2 = {
  a: 5,
  b:  'abc'
};
let a = Object.keys(value1),
  b = Object.keys(value2);
for (let x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
  if (a[x] === b[x] && value1.a[x] === value2.b[x]) {
    console.log(a[x], b[x], value1.a[x], value2.b[x]);
  }
}
```